# A list of Dart StringBuffers seem to interfere with each other

Tags: dart

I'm doing a nested iteration over two lists, in which I am populating some StringBuffers, like this:

```
  var int_list = [1, 2, 3];
  var letters_list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

  var row_strings = List.filled(3, StringBuffer());
  var single_buffer = StringBuffer();

  int_list.asMap().forEach((int_index, column) {
    letters_list.asMap().forEach((letter_index, letter) {
      // debug the writing operation
      print('writing $letter_index - $letter');

      row_strings[letter_index].write(letter);

      // try a buffer not in a list as a test
      if (letter_index == 0) {
        single_buffer.write(letter);
      }
    });
  });
  print(single_buffer);
  print(row_strings);
```

What I expect to happen is that in the list of StringBuffers, buffer 0 gets all the 'a's, buffer 1 gets all the 'b's, and buffer 3 the 'c'.

The debug output confirms that the writing operation is doing the right thing:

```
writing 0 - a
writing 1 - b
writing 2 - c
writing 0 - a
writing 1 - b
writing 2 - c
writing 0 - a
writing 1 - b
writing 2 - c
```

and the single string buffer gets the right output:

```
aaa
```

But the output of the list is this:

```
[abcabcabc, abcabcabc, abcabcabc]
```

What is going on here? There seems to be some strange behaviour when the StringBuffers are in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
  var row_strings = List.filled(3, StringBuffer());
```

This constructor is documented as:

> List.filled(int length, E fill, {bool growable: false})
>
> Creates a list of the given length with `fill` at each position.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/List.filled.html

So what you are doing is creating a single `StringBuffer` instance and uses that on every position in your `row_strings` list.

What you properly want, is to create a new `StringBuffer` for each position in the list. You need to use `List.generate` for that:

> List.generate(int length,E generator(int index), {bool growable: true})
>
> Generates a list of values.
>
> Creates a list with length positions and fills it with values created by calling generator for each index in the range 0 .. length - 1 in increasing order.

https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List/List.generate.html

Using that, we end up with:

```
  final row_strings = List.generate(3, (_) => StringBuffer());
```

We don't need the `index` argument in our generator so I have just called it `_`. The function `(_) => StringBuffer()` will be executed for each position in the list and saved. Since out function returns a new instance of `StringBuffer` each time it is executed, we will end up with a list of 3 separate `StringBuffer` instances.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!! I actually had the same incorrect use of filled() in other parts of my code but I hadn't seen the bugs from those yet!

Comment: If I do `var thislist = List.filled(2, 'string');` how come the strings are then different things, even though a string is created as an object too?

Comment: @joachim `String` are immutable so you cannot change the state of the object itself. Every operation on `String` which manipulates the state, will create a new `String` object. The same for e.g. `int` and `double`. So it is not a problem that we reuse the same `String` for each element in the list since we know that if we want to change the value, we end up creating a new object. The same cannot be said for `StringBuffer` which does contain an inner state.

Comment: Thanks again for the explanation :)

Comment: Can also use a list literal `[for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) StringBuffer()]`.